# Need assistance getting (parsing?) these JSON data into Xcode

Tags: ios, c, xcode, json, parsing

Before I start, I would like to say that I'm quite a newbie to Xcode and the C Language, and I'm trying my best to learn as much as I can. I have researched for about 2 days now before posting this question but could not find anything helpful :( I am genuinely stuck and would appreciate ANY help. This is most likely a very **simple**/basic question:

Basically, I am trying to get this data ([LINK](http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?StopCode1=59581&DirectionID=1&VisitNumber=1&ReturnList=StopCode1,StopPointName,LineName,DestinationText,EstimatedTime,MessageUUID,MessageText,MessagePriority,MessageType,ExpireTime)) which is apparrently in UTF-8 JSON and display it on a simple label on Xcode. However, I do not know how to get that data and parse it at all. I've followed a [tutorial online](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) with success, but that deals with JSON objects rather than arrays (which I think I am dealing with).

I would HIGHLY appreciate it if someone could extract/parse the data from the first link given into a basic label on Xcode in code format.Preferably with commentary on what most lines of code are doing for my own benefit, as this would really help me understand how it works. Hopefully from there, I would be able to make good progress.

Once again this is highly appreciated!

Thank YOu.

Here's a sample of the JSON URL for convenience if you don't want to click the link:

```
[4,"1.0",1343920773538]
[1,"Spring Gardens","59581","275","Barkingside",1343920940000,1343920940000]
[1,"Spring Gardens","59581","275","Barkingside",1343921717000,1343921717000]
[1,"Spring Gardens","59581","549","Loughton",1343921858000,1343921858000]
[1,"Spring Gardens","59581","275","Barkingside",1343922204000,1343922204000]
[2,"Spring Gardens","59581","8a56a0ab37b72b400137cb7cfd954038_29222",0,3,"Bus routes serving this stop are subject to change during the Olympics and Paralympics games. For more information visit www.tfl.gov.uk/buses for more information.",1344668400000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject like that tutorial shows, you should get a NSDictionary or NSArray at the end which will contain all your values just map those to the label in the end.

If you dont wan to do that, save the response in a char array and navigate through it while checking for [ or " characters when you find one read the chars until the next occurrence and save all the data you read into an array or something but this is messy and involves atleast 3-4 hours of writing your own custom logic for JSON data decryption, you should use JSONObject which is pretty simple

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your help rigy73 but none of that made any sense to me lol. 

If someone could provide me a very basic sample code extracting/parsing that data into a label, I would be EXTREMEMLY GRATEFUL. That way I can understand how to go about it, and carry on from there. 

I've been searching through Google and couldn't really see anyhting useful, hence the reason why I am desperately asking for help. 

THANK YOU once again :)

Comment: I am sorry i don't really own a mac so can't write code for you but, if you don't understand what i said, take a step backward. First learn the basics of C, learn what ASCII codes are, learn more about pointers and everything. Then move on to objective c, learn what is NSDictionary, or NSArray when they are used, then learn more about object oriented programing then coca framework and stuff like JSONObject. And after all that come back to this, this would look too simple then. Better pick up 2-3 books and go through them all...

Comment: That might seem like a lot of hard work just for a one simple JSON decoding which someone might be able to code for you in 5 minutes or less, but no one is really going to spoon feed you and give you everything.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have this same problem. I have been looking for a json solution and currently i found that the best way to deal with this data is to parse is as csv instead. The solution seems straight up when you try to parse it as CSV instead of JSON

Comment: Welcome, you should edit this answer so that the last sentence make sense - also I'm not sure this is an answer - more of a comment.